# Very slow MariaDB query when adding ORDER BY/LIMIT but there are no rows

Tags: select, order-by, mariadb-10.1, limits

I am facing an issue with MariaDB 10.1 on a log table with the following (simplified) structure:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  log_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  log_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  entity_type VARCHAR(10),
  entity_id INT UNSIGNED,
  field VARCHAR(30),
  old_value VARCHAR(255),
  new_value VARCHAR(255),
  log_message TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id INT UNSIGNED,
  INDEX (entity_type, entity_id),
  INDEX (entity_type, field),
  INDEX (log_date),
  INDEX (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

On one of our customers' database, where the table as almost 50 million rows, I am seeing a strange result, for which a query which there are no rows takes a much longer time than one where there are rows.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE entity_type = 'employee'
  AND entity_id = ID_FOR_WHICH_LOGS_EXIST
ORDER BY log_date DESC, log_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

gives a result in about 2-3 seconds, here its EXPLAIN output:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                        | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | logs          | index | entity_type,entity_type_2            | log_date | 21      | NULL | 2094 |   100.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

While another query

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE entity_type = 'employee'
  AND entity_id = INVALID_ID_OR_WITHOUT_LOGS
ORDER BY log_date DESC, log_id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

takes almost 5 minutes to complete, here is the EXPLAIN output, identical to the previous query:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                        | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | logs          | index | entity_type,entity_type_2            | log_date | 21      | NULL | 2094 |   100.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I have noticed that, in the second case, removing the LIMIT clause brings the execution time to a few milliseconds; the same happens if I change the LIMIT to have an offset, for example `LIMIT 10, 10`.

**Is there anything wrong with my queries or table structure (and, if so, how could I fix it?), or is it an issue with the database itself?**

EDIT:

I have just noticed that also the first query, if used with a LIMIT clause without offset, is slower than the same query with an offset, the execution time goes from 2-3 seconds to about 0.01 seconds.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I've edited the question with the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: It seems to have worked! Though I am not sure why ... all the WHERE columns were indexed already, so it should have quickly filtered the valid rows, before sorting, and see that there is none. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It now seems to use the index entity_type (the first one in the table definition), not the new composite index you made me test; still, much better times than before.